# How to ensure I get current date in vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date

I have the following code:

```
Public Function UltimoIngreso() As Date
    Try
        UltimoIngreso = Now.Date    'I am not ALWAYS getting the current date and time
                                    ' --other lines of code
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' An error has occured so display an error message.
        ReportBDLog.ReportErrorBD(ex, Me.GetType.ToString & "." & "UltimoIngreso" & vbCrLf & "Message: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Source: " & ex.Source & vbCrLf, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.ToString)

    End Try

End Function
```

Sometimes, but not always, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How do I ensure that Function UltimoIngreso always returns current date and time?
What am I missing?

This Function is used in an asp.net App.

Comment: You are somewhat stuck in VB6 land.  In VB.NET, you should use `Date.Now` for the current data and time and `Date.Today` for the current date with the time zeroed.  Also, you should always use a `Return` statement to return a value from a function and not assign to the implicit local variable named after the function.  If you do those things then there's no reason to get an exception unless there's something wrong with some other code that you have shown us.  Maybe you should look at the call stack of the exception to see where it was actually thrown.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you were saying.  If you want to return a value even if an exception is thrown then put a Return statement after the catch block.  As I said, if you want the current date and time then return `Date.Now` and if you want just the date then return `Date.Today`.

Comment: By the way, that is also going to get the date/time on the server, because the VB code in an ASP.NET app is executed server-side.  If you want the local date/time for the client then you'll need to use JavaScript to get it on the client.

Comment: Ok I'm going to change Now.Date for Date.Now and see if that solves the issue. I want to initialize UltimoIngreso to Date.now, but I usually change that value to a value I retrieve from sql server in the next lines. I only return the current date and time if I dont find a record in the database. So, I can not simply return date.now. That's not what I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I want the date on the server, that is ok. Also I am going to explicitly return the implicit local variable adding a Finally statement. I wasn't aware now.date is vb6 style.

Comment: "I can not simply return date.now".  That doesn't mean not using a `Return` statement.  Either declare a local variable and return that at the end or else place multiple `Return` statements that return different values in appropriate places. There's no reason not to use `Return` statements. You can write basically the exact same code as you need here in C# and you have no choice but to use `return` statements there, so there's no reason you can't here too.

Comment: "I am going to explicitly return the implicit local variable". Don't do that.  The whole point of that implicit local variable is that it gets returned implicitly.  Don't use that variable at all, ever in VB.NET.  If you want to return something then return it.  If you want a variable then declare one.  The `Now` that you were using in your code originally is the `Now` property declared in the `DateAndTime` module in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.  Pretty much all that namespace is .NET implementations of VB6 functions that exist for compatibility and have better .NET alternatives.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I hope these changes will solve the issue. The original code works perfectly on development PC, but fails randomly on the production server now and then. I discovered the issue because I keep track of exceptions on a database.